# Performing date and time calculations in Java

Tags: java, date, time

I'm trying to do simple date/time calculations and no matter what I do I'm getting confused with what appears to be time zones etc.

I need to add (and subtract)different date/times together so I figured the easiest way would be to convert them to seconds, perform the calculations and then format back to a string. But no matter what I do, I'm one hour out - which sounds like timezone/DST etc.

What's wrong with this:

```
 long dateInMillis = 3600000L;

 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

 Date dt = new Date();
 dt.setTime(dateInMillis);
 System.out.println( formatter.format(dt.getTime()));
```

The answer I get is 2:00. Even if I use:

```
 long dateInMillis = 1;
```

I still get 1:00

Help please ;-)

TIA
Martin

Comment: save yourself a lot of headache, use an existing library for this - I like JodaTime myself.

Comment: @Nim - Why not post that as an answer (maybe with some sample code) so we can give you some upvotes!

Comment: I was actually going to post this as an answer myself, but I didn't want to steal @Nim's thunder.

Comment: @Dave/Erick, I figured others would chime in with Joda anyway - I've added an answer, will update with some examples once the OP's intentions are clearer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that using Joda is likely to make life easier.  However what you are seeing is the effect of a TimeZone sensitive formatter.

You could try adding:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: That's the one!!!!!! Thanks Mark. Brilliant!! That works. I would agree with everyone else that Joda is probably better but in my case - can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself a lot of headache, use an existing library for this - I like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) myself.

For example the [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class supports various calculations (to add or subtract specific periods etc.) If you want an example, post your exact requirement, and I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.Ok - should have said at the beginning. I *have* to use the basic libraries as I'm unable to load anything else on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try and format a long as a date. Just use:

```
long dateInMillis = 3600000L;

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

Date dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(dateInMillis);
System.out.println( formatter.format(dt));
```

However, I would use a 3rd party lib for handling time-calculations like JodaTime as @Nim suggested, if your calculations are in anyway complicated.

Comment: OK - but that still gives me 2:00

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to use a framework as suggested in the comments.

However, Date is based on the milliseconds after Jan. 1st 1970. So 3600000L is just one hour from there, so 1:00 is correct.

Comment: That's just the problem. I don't 1:00, I get 2:00. BUt Mark's solution wrioks.

Answer (score 0):

According to people here, you could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to resolve this calculations. If you want to stay with pure Java code, you can look for [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to do your operations with dates. Here is a sample:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date d = c.getTime();
System.out.println(df.format(d)); //actual hour:minute
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -4);
d = c.getTime();
System.out.println(df.format(d)); //actual hour:minute minus 4 hours
```

Still, I won't rely too much in this kind of code. You'll have less problems using Joda Time.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi. I tried the calendar object but get the same results. My date/times are in seconds so can I use :

Comment: @MartinWalke it could be pretty tedious but you can even add or substract milliseconds on a Calendar instance. It would be better if you post your exact requirement and I'll edit my answer to solve it using `Calendar` methods.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi. Unfortunately, I only have the time in seconds. I would first have to convert to day/month/year/hr/mins/sec  to use the `code`.add`code` method.

Comment: @MartinWalke you can use `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); long l = c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000` so you get the time in seconds, use the value for your math operations and convert it again into a Date using `c.setTimeInMillis(l*1000)`

Comment: @MartinWalke I've already tested Mark's answer, and its the right solution for your problem :).

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `new Date()`, current date in current timezone is created. When you're  calling 'dt.setTime(dateInMillis);' you set offset in milliseconds from 1 January 1970 in GMT timezone. Let me explain, here in Msk, first call will give me `Thu Mar 01 17:02:22 MSK 2012`, the second call will give me 1 hour offset, thus in Msk it will be original offset (+3) plus 1, so it'll be `Thu Jan 01 04:00:00 MSK 1970`. Then when you're calling `formatter.format(? extends Number)` it calls `new Date(((Number)obj).longValue())` inside, so it creates back you date which is `Thu Jan 01 04:00:00 MSK 1970` and prints hours and minutes. So, you're right, it prints out time in your current timezone.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here's example code using the Joda-Time 2.3 library as mentioned by the other answers and comments.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

long dateTimeInMillis = 3600000L;  // 1,000 * 60 * 60 = 3600000L = 1 hour.

// Time Zone list… http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html  (not quite up-to-date, read page for details)
DateTime dateTimeInUtc = new DateTime( dateTimeInMillis, DateTimeZone.UTC );
// Paris happens to be one hour ahead of UTC/GMT.
DateTime dateTimeInParis = dateTimeInUtc.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeInUtc: " + dateTimeInUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInParis: " + dateTimeInParis );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInUtc: 1970-01-01T01:00:00.000Z
dateTimeInParis: 1970-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00
```